# arcpy connect to accdb with 64bit background processing

Tags: arcpy, ms-access, 64bit, background-geoprocessing

I'm trying to read from a accdb MS Access Database via python in a ArcGIS Toolbox tool. I already established a database connection (via Add OLE DB in ArcCatalog) which I can use in a 32bit python process. I have the 64bit background processing installed and don't want to set

```
self.canRunInBackground = True
```

in the Python Toolbox.
When writing something like

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(test.odc.table_name,[field_name]) as sc_rows:
    for sc_row in sc_rows:
        print sc_row[0]
```

it works perfectly fine in a 32bit python environment but in 64bit python I get the error message:
RuntimeError: cannot open

I have Windows7 64bit, ArcGIS 10.4.1 including the 64bit background processing but only a 32bit MS Office. Might that be the problem?

Is there any  way to access MS Access accdb databases from python having the 64bit background processing installed?

The documentation of ArcGIS 10.1 states that ole-db connections are not suported in 64bit background processing (http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Background_Geoprocessing_64_bit/002100000040000000/) whereas in the documentation of ArcGIS 10.4 it is not listed as unsupported data type (http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/analyze/executing-tools/64bit-background.htm).

Comment: If it's not *listed* as being supported, it's not supported. This is a Microsoft driver issue more than anything, but I don't think you'll find a way past this.

Comment: As I sad it was listed as not supported in 10.1 but it is not listed anymore in the 10.4 documentation. That's why I thought there might be a way.

Comment: ODBC is *old* technology, I can remember using it on Windows NT. Can't you see the table in ArcCatalog if you browse to it? You may not be able to see the queries from catalog but you should be able to see the JET (Access) database tables, if not create a new personal geodatabase, to setup the expected tables, and copy the table from the existing database by import records in Access.

Comment: OLE DB is an ancient protocol. Finding 64-bit drivers is the problem. I think the 10.1 warning is still applicable.

Comment: Actually, ODBC is the recommended way by esri to connect to a accdb database. I can't see them in ArcCatalog except if I create a ODBC connection. I could export the database into another format (which is, as it seems, the only workaround) but I initially wanted to avoid that and have access to the original datasources in order to avoid inconsistencies.

Comment: I was the owner of 64 bit BG; its been so long since I worked with it and OLEDB, I dont recall the specifics, but I think we did something between 10.1 and 10.4 to make OLEDB work, thus it was removed as unsupported. I seem to recall something specific to the 64bit OLEDB drivers.Just a guess, try this: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20065

Comment: This article reminds me of some of the pain: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000009382 Getting both 32bit and 64bit drivers for OLEDB installed on the same machine was difficult. I think there is a way to do it, I just can't find the information.